# Java: How to Show Only System.out.print Calls?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, println

I have built a console program in Java that uses external jars. I would like to observe my own System.out.println logs in the console, but they are being for the most part overwhelmed by messages on the console generated by some Logger (from the package org.slf4j;) which outputs massive amounts of text.

My issue is I cannot change the code that uses the Logger, because it is wrapped up in a jar and do not have its source. Is there a way to only show MY System.out.println calls? Or to otherwise quiet the messaged produced by this code I don't have source for?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe change the log level to omit the majority of messages.

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: @KevinO has a solution for your problem explained in more detail.

Comment: Are you sure the log messages are going to stdout? Try redirecting stderr and see if that doesn't eliminate them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches.

1. Change the log level or location. Unless it is set programatically, there is a configuration file for the SLF4j system. Modify the level so it displays only warn or only error. Alternatively, change the logger so that it goes to a file instead of stdout.
2. If you on a *nix system, and depending upon how you invoke the program, it is possible to do something akin to `java PROGRAM | grep -v "org.slf4j"` (or whatever the package is). This approach will remove any lines that match from the display.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a library that uses [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) for its logging, which is a fairly standard library. As helpful as it can be that there are all those libraries out there that do useful things, one of the challenges of using them is that one needs to integrate their logging into the one used by your application. SLF4J provides a standard logging interface that many libraries use, and allows them to bind to a [standard logging implementation](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping) like Logback or log4j.

I would expect that most SLF4J-using libraries would depend on the slf4j-api only, and not have a specific logging implementation binding in their dependencies. By default, SLF4J uses the "no-op" logger, meaning that no logging is output (other than an initial warning that that's what it's doing). You could add the slf4j-nop library if that's what you want for your testing, to remove all logging.

But since you're actually seeing output, it seems that the library you're using is also for some reason including a binding to an actual logging framework. At that point, your options are:

1. Figure out how that binding and actual logging framework is getting into your classpath and remove it. (If you're using Maven to manage your dependencies, for example, you might add an `<exclude>` element for them.), or
2. Figure out what logging framework is being used (If you're using Maven, I find the dependency:tree output useful), essentially adopt using it for your application as well, and configure it to log the way you want, hiding the messages that you find irrelevant.

If we had more details on how you were getting this library's dependencies in your application (I've given information for Maven as it's what I'm most familiar with and it's rather standard), or what logging framework you thereby unwittingly added to your application, somebody may be able to direct you further.